# Syncing a Local Directory to S3/SDB with Git or Mercurial

Tags: git, mercurial, amazon-s3, amazon-simpledb

I am looking for a solution in Python, since that is my programming language of choice.  Here's my problem:

I am trying to sync a directory on a client's machine to S3/SDB.  It is maybe 20k-30k pdf files that total between 6 and 10GB.

I was thinking about using a local database like SQL lite to keep track of files on the client machine, so that I could figure out what changes had been made since the last load.

However, there are already some really awesome programs that do that kind of work, namely Hg and Git.

Does anybody have any experience using a Git or Hg to watch for changes in a local filesystem?

As an added complication, I only have readonly access to this directory I need to upload, so I need some kind of way to monitor a directory that I can't actually put a ".hg" or ".git" folder in.

Comment: I know that people have done this but I'm not sure that git or hg are the best answer to the problem. Have you looked for software that does it? Cloudberry do a good line of backup software that can back up to S3 (for Windows - you didn't say what OS you are using)

Comment: The client is running Windows.  Also, I am not doing this for backups.  I am trying to sync up a number of data sources that my client has in a centralized location, and also establish relations between the various data sources.